# android how to search contacts by input strings and display results in scrollable list like in the sms messages

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext

I want to implement contacts search like we have in the build in SMS messages app, when you have a text box to enter the contact name and for each letter you insert , a scrollable list of contacts which thier name starts with the input text is displayed on screen, right under the text box. If you delete all input or can't find sutable contact then the list disappear.
When the user selects one of the list items then its full name is written in the text box.

What controls should I use to implement this behaviour? Would EditText and a regular ListView will do?

I couldn't find examples...
Please help, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use addTextChangeListener in your EditText and search value from your listview.
This [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/) can help you.

Comment: Thanks, it does helped me with the search :)
But how can I control the visibility of the listview? I want it to popup when the user enter text and to be closed when the user choose one of the list items or remove all the input

Comment: I am not sure what you asking, but if you only want to set Visible or Invisible then you can set your listview programmatically

listview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE/INVISIBLE);
as per your requirement